# How to choose a different band path for band structure calculation using VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure

How can I set a different band path for VASP calculation? For example I want to plot KGMK but not GMKG for graphene?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/k-points-value-in-kpoints-file-for-the-vasp-band-calculation

Comment: I think your question needs more clarity. How did you attempt plotting the KGMK band structure? The answer isn't far away from there.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a tool called [SeeK-path](https://tools.materialscloud.org/seekpath/) to get the high-symmetry points for your structure using the [POSCAR](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/POSCAR) file as an input. For instance, for graphene, your [POSCAR](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/POSCAR) could be

```
C
1.0
1.22800000 -2.12695839  0.00000000
1.22800000  2.12695839  0.00000000
0.00000000  0.00000000  20.
2
direct
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.25000000
   0.33333333  0.66666667  0.25000000
```

Then, [SeeK-path](https://tools.materialscloud.org/seekpath/) returns the coordinates for the high-symmetry points, suggests a $\vec{k}$ path, and even provides the suggested path in the [KPOINTS](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/KPOINTS)-file format for a band-structure calculation with VASP:

```
Special k-points for band structure
<...>  ! intersections 
line-mode
reciprocal
    0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000 1    GAMMA
    0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000 1    M 


    0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000 1    M 
    0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.0000000000 1    K 


    0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.0000000000 1    K 
    0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000 1    GAMMA


    0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000 1    GAMMA
    0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000 1    A 


    0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000 1    A 
    0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000 1    L 


    0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000 1    L 
    0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.5000000000 1    H 


    0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.5000000000 1    H 
    0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000 1    A 


    0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000 1    L 
    0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000 1    M 


    0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.5000000000 1    H 
    0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.0000000000 1    K
```

You can now adjust this file to your preference: Frist, `<...>` needs to be replaced by the number of $\vec{k}$ points between two high-symmetry points. Second, you can change the $\vec{k}$ path, e.g., by changing the order of the high-symmetry points. For instance, if you want to plot the band structure along K–$\Gamma$–M–K with 3 x 13 $\vec{k}$ points, that yields

```
K–G–M–K for graphene
13        ! intersections 
line-mode
reciprocal 
    0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.0000000000 1    K 
    0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000 1    GAMMA

    0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000 1    GAMMA
    0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000 1    M 

    0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000 1    M 
    0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.0000000000 1    K
```